# Error "value is missing" in replace_na function from tidyr

Tags: r, replace, tidyr, na

In a column of my dataset (participant ID) I have one NA value due to an earlier programming mistake in my experiment. However, I know the exact value that is supposed to be there and tried to replace the NA with this exact value.
Weird thing is, it worked the whole time - now I downloaded the same dataset again, just with more/new participant data, and tried to run my R script and it's giving me the same error over and over.

The first two lines are the code that I originally used (and that worked), the following is a different attempt but results in the same error message:

```
data_rawScales %>% 
  replace_na(list(P_ID = '56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0')) -> data_rawScales

data_rawScales %>% dplyr::mutate(P_ID = replace_na(P_ID, "56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0"))
```

The error message I receive is the following:

```
Error in replace_na(., list(P_ID = "56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0")) : argument "value" is missing, with no default"
```

I have really no clue why it worked first and now it doesn't. I tried before and after updating R studio, cleaned the environment and quit R Studio completely several times. I also checked the column and this is really the only value that's missing. I searched the internet but couldn't find anything related to this error message. Any clue what all of a sudden is wrong with this code?
Thanks!

Comment: did you load tidyr before calling replace_na() ?

Comment: @jeffreyohene  yes, I loaded the whole tidyverse library

Comment: Your question should not be edited to include an answer or marked as "solved" in the title. Stack Overflow works by allowing the community to vote on answer. Instead, post your solution as an "answer" below. You are free to accept your own answer, but other's may still answer as well and the community can decide which answer to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data_rawScales %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(P_ID = ifelse(is.na(P_ID), 
                                    replace_na(P_ID, "56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0"),
                                    P_ID))
```

Comment: I receive the same error - BUT: I figured it out in the meanwhile. Apparently in the process of writing my script I loaded more packages and forgot about them so the replace_na function was masked. If I call 
"data_rawScales %>% 
  tidyr::replace_na(list(P_ID = '56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0')) -> data_rawScales" it works - but thank you for your attempt. I'll close the question.

Comment: You don't need `replace_na` if you are using `ifelse`. You could do `ifelse(is.na(P_ID), "56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0", P_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself - apparently I had loaded additional packages while writing the script that now masked the replace_na function of tidyr.

So indicating the specific package solved the problem.

Here's the code that works now:

```
data_rawScales %>% 
  tidyr::replace_na(list(P_ID = '56138320cd28ef4dc6be3d0')) -> data_rawScales
```